# Выборка из базы посредством EF без учета регистра

Tags: c#, строки, entity-framework

В  базе в в таблице Customer есть поле FirstName.  Содержание его может быть абсолютно рандомного регистра, например, "ИвАНов". Естественно если я буду проверять на "Иванов" результат будет пустой. Сделать c.FirstName.Upper() естественно не дает.

```
var customers = t.Customers
        .Where(c => c.FirstName.Contains(findToolStripTextBox.Text);
```

Текущий вариант кода(t = new mydb:DbContext). Как это сделать правильно?

StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase - это тоже не работает.

Comment: А если в бд соответствующее поле привести в порядок и в дальнейшем заносить в таком же виде: приводим к виду *Фамилия* и на клиенте перед поиском введенное пользователем делаем так же

Comment: Укажите, какую именно СУБД вы используете. Опишите, как была создана БД (code first, database first, etc), с какими настройками. EF по умолчанию не учитывает регистр, в большинстве случаев.

Comment: postgres 9.3   code-first

Comment: К единому виду привести проблемно, да и не правильно это... Есть двойные фамилии, с пробелами и тп.

Comment: не забывайте указывать ник пользователя с предшествующим символом `@` вида *@Ник пользователя* (необходимо для получения нотификации). как вариант можно попробовать сформировать *сырой* `sql` запрос что то типа: `context.Customers.SqlQuery("Select * from Customers where FirstName like '%@firstName%'", new SqlParameter() {});`

Comment: Вроде тут решение есть, посмотрите: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison

Comment: @Сергей в данном решение есть один небольшой **ньюанс** который надо учитывать: данные предварительно **материализуются** (т.е. вытягиваются все строки на клиента) и потом уже на клиенте происходит *окончательная* фильтрация

Answer (score 1):

Приведите к одному регистру и сравнивайте:

```
var customers = t.Customers
    .Where(c => c.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(findToolStripTextBox.Text.ToLower());
```